# Clearing Value on Multiple Inputs?

Tags: jquery, variables, focus, blur

I have a jQuery script below that clears the value of an input on focus and puts it back on blur if the input remains empty. It works great, but here's the problem:

Let's say I have 3 input fields on the same page. I click on the first one with the value "Name", *defaultValue* variable becomes "Name" and the field clears. If I click out, the value goes back to "Name". Now if I click on the second field without refreshing the page, it clears just fine, but when I click outside, instead of getting the value "Initials", it gets the value of the first field.

So how can I get the *defaultValue* variable to update itself every time I click on a field?

```
var adaugaInput = $('form#adauga input:text');

adaugaInput.focus(function() {
    var defaultValue = $(this).val();
    if($(this).attr("value") == defaultValue) $(this).attr("value", "");
    adaugaInput.blur(function() {
        if($(this).attr("value") == "") $(this).attr("value", defaultValue);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The explanation for why your code works the way it does is kind-of complicated.  For every input field, you're establishing (and re-establishing, on every "focus" event!) handlers for "blur" events on *all* the inputs. It's confusing and hard to think about, so I'll just sum it up and say "don't do it that way."

```
adaugaInput.focus(function() {
  var input = $(this);
  if (!input.data('default')) input.data('default', input.val());
  if (input.val() === input.data('default'))
    input.val('');
});

adaugaInput.blur(function() {
  var input = $(this);
  if (input.val() === '') input.val(input.data('default'));
});
```

Note that I use ".val()" to get/set the "value" attribute of the input fields. Also, the "blur" handler is set up *outside* the "focus" handler. This code uses the jQuery ".data()" mechanism to keep the per-element default value. Not tested but it's probably pretty close.

With a mechanism like this, it's sometimes nice to re-style the input so that (for example) the default value shows up with a lighter font color. To do that, you'd remove and add a class to the input field, and affect the style with CSS. (The inputs would have to start off with the class; or I suppose you could apply the class on focus.)

Comment: +1 This is probably the correct way the implementation should work. Plus, I've just *borrowed* the code for a page on my own project. :)

Comment: Thanks, this worked. The only reason I used blur inside focus was because of the defaultValue variable, which I couldn't use if blur was outside.

Comment: Right, well I'm a big fan of ".data()" :-)

Answer (score 0):

i usually use this code which works :)

http://www.eggchops.com/web-stuff/jquery/jquery-clear-focus-function/

here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var clearMePrevious = ”;

// clear input on focus
$(’.clearMeFocus’).focus(function() {
  if($(this).val()==$(this).attr(’title’)) {
    clearMePrevious = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(”);
  }
});

// if field is empty afterward, add text again
$(’.clearMeFocus’).blur(function() {
  if($(this).val()==”) {
    $(this).val(clearMePrevious);
  }
});
});
```

Comment: Keeping just one variable for every field is the problem he already has.

Comment: im suggestng he just use this function. just add a clearMeFocus class on the textfield and it works no matter how many it is

Comment: I see what you mean. Well I wouldn't do it that way, but it probably would work OK. It's certainly better than the original.

Answer (score -1):

I'd go the other way around, saving defaultValue first, then binding focus:

```
var adaugaInput = $('form#adauga input:text');

adaugaInput.each(function(){
    var defaultValue = $(this).val();
        $(this).focus(function() {

        if($(this).attr("value") == defaultValue) $(this).attr("value", "");
    });
    $(this).blur(function() {
        if($(this).attr("value") == "") $(this).attr("value", defaultValue);
    });
});
```

Standard disclaimers apply, the above code is not tested. (edit: fixed mulitple blur binds)

Comment: I don't think you should be re-applying the "blur" handler on each call to the "focus" handler!